# For each row in a table, count the number of times that row is referenced by another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables in an SQLite database, authors and threads:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS authors(
    author_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS threads(
    thread_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    author_id INTEGER REFERENCES authors
);
```

Each row in `threads` references the `authors` table. Authors can be referenced by multiple threads. I need to get the names of each author and the count of threads that reference them, sorted by the count. Assuming there are four authors; Judy, John, Jim, Jane and 30 threads, the query would return something like this:

```
author.name   Count
Jane          10
Judy          8
John          8
Jim           4
```

What's the query that will return this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a join:

```
SELECT authors.name,
       COUNT(*) AS count
FROM authors
LEFT JOIN threads USING (author_id)
GROUP BY author_id
```

An alternative would be a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
SELECT name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM threads
        WHERE author_id = authors.author_id
       ) AS count
FROM authors
```

(This would be useful if you need to compute multiple, independent aggregate values for each row).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(t.thread_id) as [Count]
FROM authors a
INNER JOIN threads t
        ON a.author_id = t.author_id
GROUP BY a.author_id, a.name
ORDER BY COUNT(t.thread_id) DESC
```

Comment: Yeah, sure, you should use LEFT JOIN if you want to see information about authors without threads.